# Web application - Lock orientation to landscape on web app load

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

**Target**

I am developing an app that should stay in landscape mode on phone (always)

**Code**

Below is the code that I am doing to achieve it however its not working an I am getting the below error:

```
var locOrientation = screen.lockOrientation || screen.mozLockOrientation || screen.msLockOrientation || screen.orientation.lock;
locOrientation('landscape');
```

**Error**

```
Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect by adding the desired orientation mode in your web app `manifest.json` file:

```json
{
  "orientation":  "landscape"
}
```

and then include it in head of your template:

```html
<head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json">
</head>
```

You can learn more about web app manifest [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/)

Comment: its not working, one more thing is that I need to do it via javascript